# JS Timer, clearInterval() doesn't clear the timer. When restart, it resumes instead of restarting at zero

Tags: javascript, oop, timer

**Well the title already says it. I am working on a timer, but when I let it run for around 10 secs, press space (space = keycode 13), then it stops and then if I press space again to start, it resumes but then +2 secondes. (started at e.g. 18 sec and resumes from 20 sec) which comes from the clearInterval ID it return I think... not sure.**

*If you guys could help me out, that'd be great.*

If you have any suggesstions to do things differently, let me know too!

I'm open for all the feedback I get and improvement / tips on my code! :)

**Javascript**

```
var Timer = function() {

var self = this,
    div = document.querySelector('.timer'),
    hours, minutes, seconds, millsecs;

this.oldDate = new Date().getTime();
this.newDate;

this.isRunning = false;

this.time;

this.timerId = 0;

this.start = function() {
    self.isRunning = true;
    if (self.isRunning) {
        self.timerId = setInterval(function() {

            self.time = new Date().getTime() - self.oldDate;
            self.time = self.time.toString();

            millsecs= self.time.substr(-3);
            seconds = (Math.floor(self.time / 1000) % 60) + '.';
            minutes = (self.time >= 60000) ? (Math.floor(self.time / (1000*60)) % 60) + ':' : '';
            hours   = (self.time >= 86400) ? (Math.floor(self.time / (1000*60*60)) % 24) + ':' : '';

            div.innerHTML = hours + minutes + seconds + millsecs;
        }, 10);
    }
}

this.stop = function() {
    self.isRunning = false;
    clearInterval(obj.timerId);
    self.timerId = 0;
    }

};




var obj = new Timer();

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {

    if(e.keyCode == 32 && obj.isRunning == false) {
       obj.start();
    }

    else if (e.keyCode == 32 && obj.isRunning == true) {
        obj.stop();
    }

});
```

Comment: please use text style to highlight important parts of your question ..

Comment: Using setTimeout or setInterval with such a tiny delay is not reliable. Also it will prevent CPU nap for no good reason. Use requestAnimationFrame.